# Bootstrap 4 - Custom animated hamburger icon closed on page load?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I may be using the following `default-toggler` for bootstrap in a more old school manner, but I cannot figure out why my custom edits are forcing the button to load closed?

> [As in ' X ']

It's more than likely a rookie error and my inexperience with BS4 showing, but I would appreciate it if anyone could offer some advice.

Heres a [demo JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/k1nz4L3h/3/) with my edits in full.

**HTML**

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.icon-bar:nth-child(2) {
  width: 16px;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover > .icon-bar:nth-child(2){
  width: 22px;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}
.navbar-toggler:active > .icon-bar:nth-child(2){
  width: 22px;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 4px);
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease all .2s;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(4px, -4px);
  transition: ease all .2s;
}
```

Any assistance I could get with this would be awesome, many thanks in advance.

Regards, -B.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use class collapsed for button

```
<button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

code sample - https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/k1nz4L3h/6/

Comment: JSFiddle no longer exists.